# Error establishing a database connection (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a really hard time figuring this out... My website shows up "Error establishing a database connection" on occasion. This happens about once a day. As soon as I reboot the droplet, the problem's gone.

I've tried adding the following 2 lines in my wp-config file, as suggested on some other forums, but it didn't work:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); 
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

From what I read around the web, it seems that 512mb of RAM is perfectly fine for a wordpress multisite, if set correctly - though I'm having a hard time with a single (low content) site, without many plugins. I've also disabled/deleted the plugins that could potentially eat up a lot of memory, such as wp-backup.

If you have any suggestions for me, I'd be more than thankful! Please notice that I'm pretty new with all this, and as it's my first time running VPS, I do have a bit hard time understanding how everything works, at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

**I have already faced this issue, I have fixed this in wp-config.php**

Most of the time this error message is caused by a problem in the wp-config file.

Add this code in wp-config.php

```
define(‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);
```

yourdomain.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Click repair and optimize button to repair your database.

> Make sure you remove this line of code after you have fixed your
>   database connection error message.

If you still have this issues, contact your hosting provider. They will fix this easily.